# ASP.NET code first doesn't create DB or Tables

Tags: asp.net, database, ef-code-first

I'm trying to add a new connection to database in an ASP.NET application, and I'm trying to use code-first initialization.

For now, that are my connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Auth-20211221042302.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Auth-20211221042302;Integrated Security=True"  
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DriveMeConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DriveMe-App-20211231001122.mdf;Initial Catalog=DriveMe-App-20211231001122;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The first, `DefaultConnection`, was generated for the ASP.NET authentication, and works well.

The second, `DriveMeConnection`, is the database I want to create from my code-first model.

So, I created a new `DbContext` as usual:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Azienda> Aziende;
    public DbSet<ClientePrivato> ClientiPrivati;
    public DbSet<Fornitore> Fornitori;
    public DbSet<Auto> ParkAuto;
    public DbSet<Guidatore> Guidatori;
    public DbSet<Pratica> Pratiche;

    public DatabaseContext() : base("name=DriveMeConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

(there's no difference if I use `base("name=DriveMeConnection")` or `base("DriveMeConnection")`).

When I am trying to read something, for example

```
using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    List<Fornitore> lst = db.Fornitori.ToList();
}
```

`Fornitori` table was not created. In this case, the whole database wasn't created.

I tried to add

```
Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DatabaseContext>());
```

inside the `DatabaseContext` constructor, but nothing changes.

I tried to add

```
this.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

inside the `DatabaseContext` constructor, the database was created, but the tables aren't there.

I tried to force initialization with:

```
using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    db.Database.Initialize(force: true);
}
```

This creates the database, but it is still empty without tables.

What did I miss?

Comment: If you want EF to create your database objects, you need to use **migrations** - have you done that? Those migrations are generated C# classes that will generate the tables, views, etc. and allow EF to do this work for you

Comment: I'm following some tutorials, and in that tutorials don't talk about migrations... 
I didn't used migrations yet, in my mind the datamodel should be enough for create the database... I'll try the migrations way... Thanks!

Comment: I followed this guide, here talks about migrations only for modify the database after the creation, but it should create the database and the tables automatically. What I miss?

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved, without migrations that I don't need **for now**, I only call this function at startup.

```
public static void FirstConfiguration()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DatabaseContext>());
    var context = new DatabaseContext();
    context.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

And in the DbContext, the dataset need to be properties with the get and set method:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Azienda> Aziende { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClientePrivato> ClientiPrivati { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fornitore> Fornitori { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Auto> ParkAuto { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Guidatore> Guidatori { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pratica> Pratiche { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext() : base("name=DriveMeConnection")
    {
    }
}
```